# Mysql status connection increases many times with just one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

The hosting site provides me with 1500 connections per hour. Now i am not very good at Mysql so i searched way to check connections and found out that even one query incremented connection by many times. Here is a picture before doing a query.

[image]

and this is after running one query.

[image]

Now if even one query incremented my connections by 100. wont i run out of my connections after 15 or more queries?

Also kindly tell me a way to clear these stats so i can test again with more precision

Comment: This seems like a conversation to have with your host

Comment: Are you running the stats from some tool/IDE? It could be that the tool does a lot in the background, but this sounds like a bit to much for this. Try to check the stats and running the query from the command prompt. Also try to check which queries are running and you might get more hints: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST will list all running queries.

Comment: @MrApnea i am running the command ' SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections" ' in SQL query box.

Comment: Not familiar with that tool so I can't say how it works underneath. But I would do as Strawberry says and try to talk to your host, they must have some support and can probably check why there are so many connections.

Comment: @MrApnea ok I have contacted them.